# Israel-Wilson-Perjés Solutions

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, resource-recommendations

I'm searching for a reference that gives explicitly the field strength (or at least the gauge fields) of the [Israel-Wilson-Perjés Solution](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=israel+wilson+perjes), using complex harmonic functions for the metric.

In "Gravity and Strings" by Ortin, one can find the required formula at pag. 280, but I'm not able to verify that it is solution to the equation of motion, therefore I suspect that there is some misprint in the formulas for the gauge fields.

EDIT: Indeed there was a misprint in the first edition of the book, that is corrected in the second edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a misprint in the first edition of the book, now corrected in the second edition.